# Write a function that calculates log base 2 of a given number

Tags: python, logic, calculator

I'm a newbie at python so sorry in advance is this is a really simple problem.

**Question:** We are asked to write a custom function that calculates `b` in `log_2(x) = b` given `x` (log base 2 of x).

Note: The variable `x` is given as float and we are not allowed to use any of python's built-in functions like pow() or import any packages.

**Examples:**

```
Given 8, return "3"
Given 9, return "between 3 and 4"
Given 0.4, return "between -1 and -2"
```

All return types take the format of a string (we are allowed to use str()).

**My attempt:** Since `log_2(x) = b` essentially equals to `2^b = x`, I tried iterating over the value b and see if the `x` value is equal to the given number. However, I forgot that the given number is a float, and not an integer.

```
def log_base_2(number: float) -> str:
    power = 0
    BASE = 2

    if number <= 0:
        raise Exception('Sorry, your input is incorrect!') 

    while True:
        if number == calc_power(BASE, power):
            return str(power)
        elif number > calc_power(BASE, power) and number < calc_power(BASE, power + 1):
            return f"between {power} and {power + 1}"
        else:
            power += 1
 

# helper method for calculating the power
def calc_power(base: float, power: float):
    if power == 0:
        return 1

    multiple = base
    for i in range (1, power):
        base *= multiple 
    return base
```

This doesn't work essentially because I've only taken integers into consideration and that it can't calculate floats.

I'm not very sure how to write an exponent calculator that would calculate a float type power. I'd appreciate any help and if you an easier way to solve this problem please let me know!

Comment: Can you please show a few examples where the result of your code is different than what it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer by rewriting your current function:

```
def log_base_2(number: float) -> str:
    power = 0
    BASE = 2
    power2 =0
    # create new power variable that counts -ve

    if number <= 0:
        raise Exception('Sorry, your input is incorrect!') 

    while True:
        if number == calc_power(BASE, power):
            return str(power)
        elif number > calc_power(BASE, power) and number < calc_power(BASE, power + 1):
            return f"between {power} and {power + 1}"
        elif number < calc_power(BASE, power2) and number > calc_power(BASE, power2-1):
            return f"between {power2} and {power2-1}"
        # this elif wants to also check powers in the negative direction
        else:
            power += 1
            power2 -= 1
            # increment -ve power
 

# helper method for calculating the power
def calc_power(base: float, power: float):
    if power == 0:
        return 1
    multiple = base
    
    if power < 0: # check for -ve powers
            power *= -1 # change power to +ve
            for i in range(power,1,-1): # loop backwards
                multiple *= 2 # 2^power
            base = (1 / multiple) # to be a -ve power, it must be inverse
    else:
        for i in range (1, power):
            base *= multiple
    return base
```

There might be a better way that involves less function calls but this is what I can think of right now.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I do have one question tho. When I separated the `calc_power(base, power)` function and tried `calc_power(3, -5)`, the result is different from what it actually is.

Comment: It would most likely be this line `multiple *= 2`. It was written with base 2 in mind but it should be an easy fix. Change the 2 to base.